# In $(\mathbb{Z},<)$ is it possible to define the operation of addition?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, integers

We know that in the language $L=\{+,*\}$, it is possible define the natural order $\geq$ on $(\mathbb{Z},+,*)$ in the following way:

$a\geq b$ if and only if $a-b$ is a sum of 4 squares.

In fact, by the theorem of 4 squares, we have that each positive natural number can be written as sum of 4 squares. In this way we get a necessary and sufficient condition of an integer number to be positive and this condition depends only by the language $L$.

The question is the following: 
Is it true a sort of inverse implication?

Is it possibile define the sum operation of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the language $\{\geq\}$?

Comment: I believe one can define the predecessor and successor of an integer using only $\leq$. Is that enough?

Comment: Is it  possible define a successor because you can use the well-ordering principle? Infact for each $k\in Z$ you can consider the set $A=\{a>k\}$ that it’s isomorphic to $(\mathbb{N},>)$ that it is well-ordered. So there exists a minimum for $A$ and we can define $k+1:=min A$.

Comment: @FedericoFallucca You still need to pick a $0$ to define addition in terms of successor.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Even including $0$ isn't enough - first-order logic doesn't in general allow recursive definitions. (But this is harder to show, since $(\mathbb{Z}, 0,\le)$ is rigid.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber What you're saying is that in the language $(\mathbb Z, 0, \le)$, there's no predicate $\mathrm{Add}(x,y,z)$ such that $x + y = z$ in the standard model of $\mathbb Z$, right?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, that's correct. Note that this is what we mean when we talk about a function being (un)definable in a structure: that there is (no) formula in the language of that structure which, in that structure, defines the graph of the function in question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $X=\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{Z}$ with the lexicographic order.  Identifying $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\{0\}\times\mathbb{Z}$ in $X$, then $(\mathbb{Z},\geq)$ is elementarily embedded in $(X,\geq)$ (you can prove this using Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games, for instance).  If addition were definable (even with parameters) in $(\mathbb{Z},\geq)$, the same definition would give an addition operation that makes $(X,\geq)$ into an ordered abelian group.  But that is impossible since $X$ has elements greater than every integer but not any elements less than every integer to be their negatives.

If you more strongly want addition to be definable *without parameters*, then there's a much simpler argument that it's impossible: the map $f(x)=x+1$ is an automorphism of $(\mathbb{Z},\geq)$.  If addition were definable without parameters, then $f$ would preserve addition, but $f(x+y)=x+y+1$ whereas $f(x)+f(y)=x+y+2$.

Comment: Why did you delete your original automorphism answer (which I just saw after posting mine)? Is there something obvious I'm missing there? It seems to work ...

Comment: It works only for definability without parameters.

Comment: That's worth saying explicitly, since it's not part of the question (and explains the value of your answer over the simpler automorphism argument).

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible. (Although things like successor and predecessor are definable - e.g. $Pred(x)=y$ iff $y< x$ and $\forall z(z<x\implies z\le y)$.) One way to see this is by considering automorphisms of the structure in question. The map $$f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}: z\mapsto z+14$$ (say) is an automorphism of the structure $(\mathbb{Z},\le)$, and hence must preserve any relation or function *definable in* $(\mathbb{Z},\le)$. However, we have $$3+1=4\quad\mbox{ but }\quad f(3)+f(1)=3+14+1+14=32\color{red}{\not=}18=f(3+1).$$ We can also prove stronger results, concretely classifying all possible relations and functions definable in $(\mathbb{Z},\le)$  (and then just checking that $+$ isn't on the list). But such an approach takes more work.

---

Of course, this method has drawbacks. For example, consider the expansion $(\mathbb{Z},0,\le)$. This structure is *rigid* (= no nontrivial automorphisms), so we can't use the argument above to show that anything is undefinable. Yet addition is still undefinable in this structure - it just requires a more intricate argument, such as Eric Wofsey's answer. Relevant tools for proving general undefinability results include *Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games* and *quantifier elimination (of expansions)*.